# Always prompts for username and password when printing

Tags: networking, windows, printing, 18.04

Every time I try to connect to a Windows 10 printer server as a guest user, Ubuntu always prompts for credentials. If I write my credentials (username and password from Windows account), it successfully prints. But I want to print as a guest (The printer is shared to allow guests to print).

This happens with Ubuntu 18.04. Another computer with Lubuntu 16.04 works well (It does not ask for credentials and prints ok in Windows machine).

Can someone help me? Or confirm if it is a bug with 18.04 cups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've decided to take a different approach and connect via LPD server. Windows 7, 8 and 10 have a built-in LPD server. It can be activated in the Control Panel under Programs -> Activate Windows functions in the section Print services. Then the printer can be added in CUPS, choosing LPD protocol.

The printer address will look like this: lpd://windowspc/printersharename (in my case, I had to use an IP address. So, it looked like this: lpd://192.168.1.x/printersharename).

And it works! Yay! :)

Comment: A big thank you for this!! 5 years later and the bug is still there.. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1849859 . Your solution worked like a charm.